# Creating duplicates of rows in a SQL table while changing one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

Let's say I have a Sample Table:

```
characterid Primay Key
charactername
charatertype
picture1
picture2
```

Also, let's say there are thousands of rows in this table.

I want to select all the: `where characterid like 'a%'` rows, and then create a duplicate rows of those selected while altering their 'characterid's. Since characterid is the primary key and I can't have any duplicates.

The newly inserted rows will have similar characterids except for the first letter 'a' which will be changed to 'b'.

This is how far i've gone so far:

```
INSERT INTO sample
    SELECT * FROM sample WHERE characterid LIKE 'a%';
```

Comment: please tag the appropriate database (don't tag multiple) and post your attempt at solving this.

Comment: vkp, yep. just added the adjustment.

Comment: should all the other column values be retained?

Comment: vkp, yes. I just want exact copy of the rows except for the characterid. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the first character in the character id using concat and substr function:

```
INSERT INTO sample (characterid, charactername, charatertype, picture1, picture2) 
SELECT concat('b',SUBSTR (characterid, 2, len(characterid()) , charactername, charatertype, picture1, picture2
  FROM sample WHERE characterid like  'a%';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is expressed as:

```
INSERT INTO sample (characterid, charactername, charatertype, picture1, picture2) 
    SELECT 'b' || SUBSTR(characterid, 2), . . .
      FROM sample WHERE characterid like  'a%';
```

Postgres does not need the third argument to `substr()`.